# how to but button in fixed place

Tags: android, xml

i work on android application
i work on implementation of my design 
i try to implement this part of my design

http://new.karkira.com/capture.jpg

i can't add image yet please check it on server

i try absolute layout and linear layout but no one of both work seccessfully

i spend my day to solve it in standard way , but i don't find the right solution

please help me 
thanks in advance

i try do that using Linear layout 
this is my code

`

`enter code here`

```
   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="0dip"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/imageView3"
       android:background="@drawable/bar"

       android:layout_weight="4"/>


   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="20dip"
       android:layout_height="50dip"
       android:id="@+id/imageView4"
       android:background="@drawable/twitter"
       android:paddingBottom="10dip"
       android:layout_weight="1"/>


   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="20dip"
       android:layout_height="50dip"
       android:id="@+id/imageView5"
       android:background="@drawable/facbook"

       android:layout_weight="1"/>

   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="20dip"
       android:layout_height="50dip"
       android:id="@+id/imageView6"
       android:background="@drawable/instagram"

       android:layout_weight="1"/>

   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="0dip"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/imageView7"
       android:background="@drawable/bar"

       android:layout_weight="4"/>
```

`

Comment: Please post the code that you've tried.

Comment: Do you have the three images separately?

Comment: yes , i add my try to my quastion

Comment: Why you have 5 images views but in the jpeg only three images?

Comment: i divide my shape into five part 2 stright line and thre circle 
and i  try to concatenate it

Comment: instead of doing that you should have the top level Layout(example linearlayout) have a straight line background and three imageViews on top.

Comment: i will try that , thanks